# Сложная форма в w2ui

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Не могу разобраться с w2ui...
В общем, по нажатию на кнопку открывается страничка с формой, в которой одна строка с полями - одна запись в базу данных. А снизу две кнопки, одна отправляет данные на сервер, а вторая добавляет строку в форму
Вопрос в том, как добавить такую строку и учитывать ещё при отправке
Буду крайне признателен помощи
[image: Пример того, как я это представляю]

А, и можно ли эту форму поместить в попап? О_о